# C#. I keep getting an error stating I have "use of an unassigned local variable 'fullname'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

//I have to create a program that determines if the name is written in the correct format, then once it deems it correct it separates the first and last name.

```
public partial class nameFormatForm : Form
{
    public nameFormatForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool IsValidFullName(string str)
    {
        bool letters;
        bool character;
        bool fullname;

        foreach (char ch in str)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(ch) && str.Contains(", "))
            {
                fullname = true;
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full name is not in the proper format");
            }
        }
        return fullname;
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void clearScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exitButton.Focus();
        displayFirstLabel.Text = "";
        displayLastLabel.Text = "";
        nameTextBox.Text = "";
    }

    private void formatNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearScreenButton.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: assign an initial value to fullname ie: `bool fullname = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Always remember these 3 rules for C#:

1. To use a variable, it must be initialized.
2. Field members are initialized with a default value
3. Locals are NOT initialized with a default value.

You are breaking rule 1: Using `fullname` before it is initialized. The following program will clarify this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is a local and NOT initialized
        int number;
        var person = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(person.age); // This will work
        Console.WriteLine(number); // This will not work
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    // This is a field so it will be initialized to the default of int which is zero
    public int age;
}
```

To fix your issue, you need to initialize `fullname`:

```
bool fullname = false;
```

I would rename the variable to a more readable name such as `isFullName`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable with no initial value and then returning it in a method with an `if` statement that does not determine the value doesn't make any sense. You have to assign a value to `fullname` if you want to `return` its value.

Init this variable first:

```
bool fullname = false;
```